# Find <span> value after ko.applyBindings

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

I'm getting some values from webapi using knockout.js and then result of that (holded in span) I'm trying to use in the other place (input in table row). Result I'm showing this way:

```
<h3 data-bind="foreach: book">
    <span data-bind="text: Hotel" class="label label-info"/>
    <span data-bind="text: Номер" class="label label-info"/>
    <span class="label label-info" data-bind=" text: Фамилия"/>
    <span class="label label-info ad" data-bind=" text: Колчел"/>
    <span class="label label-info ch" data-bind=" text: Дети"/>
</h3>
```

and this is knockout code:

```
    <script>
            function BookViewModel(baseUri) {
                var self = this;
                self.Номер = ko.observable("");
                self.Колчел = ko.observable("");
                self.Дети = ko.observable("");
                self.Фамилия = ko.observable("");
                self.Hotel = ko.observable("");
                var book = {
                    Номер: self.Номер,
                    Колчел: self.Колчел,
                    Дети: self.Дети,
                    Фамилия: self.Фамилия,
                    Hotel: self.Hotel
                };
                self.book = ko.observable();
                self.books = ko.observableArray();
                $.getJSON(baseUri, self.book);
            }
            $(document).ready(function () {
                var url = location.href.split("/")
                var baseUri;
                if (url[4].toString = 'x') {
                    baseUri = '/api/xTourist/' + url[5];
                }
                else if (url[4].toString = 'y') {
                    baseUri = '/api/yTourist/' + url[5];
                }
                ko.applyBindings(new BookViewModel(baseUri));
    //This is how I'm trying to read result and use this result in input field in the other table.
 var ad = $("span.ad").val();
            var ch = $("span.ch").val();
                $("#gvOrders tr input.pax_ad").each(function () {
                    $(this).val(ad);
                });
                $("#gvOrders tr input.pax_ch").each(function () {
                    $(this).val();
                });
            });
        </script>
```

Unfortunately this var is undefrined. I'm really don't understand why values cannot be readed after ko already apply binding.

Comment: Is there any way you could add some data-binding to the #tgvOrders element?  That way, you could let knockout do the updates for you.  Showing your HTML would help as well.  Also, should your foreach be operating on "book" or "books"?  Finally, your $.getJSON call has no callback so the data returned isn't used.

Comment: Patrick, thanks for the answer. #gvOrders is asp.net control that rendered by server. I can add there foreach only in <table> element but not in <tbody> (unless use jquery to add this attribute on document.ready). foreach: as I undestand should opearte on books (I'm new to knockout, so just modifiyng examples but without real understanding). How should I add callback to $.getJson? What is this  for?

Answer (score 0):

The [knockout documentation](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/introduction.html) is really good.  I suggest you start there to help get a better understanding of how knockout works.  It'll really save you some time and frustration.

As for the $.getJSON call, the [documentation](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.getjson/) has lots of information and examples.